# How insert data to database using Maven

Tags: database, maven, maven-plugin

I have SQL script files with inserts statements:

```
Insert into TABLE (COL1, COL2) values ('1','value');
...
```

Is it possible to build Maven goal which will execute this SQL in the database?

I consider using Oracle or Postgresql database.

Comment: Do you need them for integration tests?

Comment: I need them in development phase. I want to execute this goal manually - from time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the maven-sql-plugin like this:

You can store your plain sql 'my-needed-sql.sql'.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                   <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
                   </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database</url>
                <username>postgres</username>
                <password>postgres</password>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <delimiter>/</delimiter>
                        <delimiterType>normal</delimiterType>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>

                         <srcFiles>
                             <srcFile>my-needed-sql.sql</srcFile>
                             </srcFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: @SWiggels Thank for answer. But what do you think about age of maven-sql-plugin? In: 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/sql-maven-plugin/1.5 
is info that version 1.5 was released in 2011. Is it a problem, or not?

Comment: It is only detail, but I think that you make a mistake in postgresql dependency. Your version isn't accessible from postgresql groupId: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql.

Comment: You were right i edited the postgres part. it works now.

Comment: Thanks also to @Charnjeet Singh - your advice is also helpful.

Comment: @SWiggels Who says it's no more maintained? https://github.com/mojohaus/sql-maven-plugin

Comment: I deleted my comment about not "project no more maintained"  because it is wrong. The project is still running as it seems thanks to khmarbaise!